# Weird behaviour of sortable UI jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've made a simple jQuery which allows me to drag boxes into placeholders. This works fine, but when I try to sort those placeholders (even before dragging a box into them), it has a weird behaviour...

**Removed the original code as the snippet shows my problem.**

```js
$(function() {

 $("#dropzone").sortable({

  revert: true,
  opacity: 0.5

 });

 $("#draggable li").draggable({

  connectToSortable: ".items",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: true,
  opacity: 0.5

 });

 $("li.placeholder").droppable({
  revert: false,

  drop: function (event, ui) {

   var dragging = ui.draggable.clone();

   $(this).append(dragging);

  }

 });

 $("ul, li").disableSelection();

});
```

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 80%;
}

ul#draggable, ul#dropzone {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

ul#draggable li.to-drag {
 background-color: #d1d1d1;
 border: 2px solid #909090;
 cursor: move;
 float: left;
 height: 100px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
}

ul#dropzone li.placeholder {
 background-color: #efefef;
 border: 2px dashed #c1c1c1;
 cursor: move;
 float: left;
 height: 100px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
}

.correct {
 border: 2px solid #44871f;
}

.to-drop {
 background-color: #fefefe;
 border: 2px solid #44871f;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>

    <title>Drag & Drop</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="drag-drop.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    
  <div class="wrap">

  <ul id="draggable" class="items">

    <li class="to-drag" class="items">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </li>

    <li class="to-drag" class="items">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </li>

    <li class="to-drag" class="items">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </li>

    <li class="to-drag" class="items">
      <h1>4</h1>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <div style="height: 100px; clear: both;"></div>

  <ul id="dropzone">

    <li class="placeholder"></li>
    <li class="placeholder"></li>
    <li class="placeholder"></li>
    <li class="placeholder"></li>

  </ul>

  </div>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: and what is this weird behaviour?

Comment: What is the "weird behaviour"?

Comment: When I sort those placeholders, the moment I drop the placeholder, the sorting works fine, but there is a clone of the element where I let go of my mouse. (No idea how to translate that in english).

In short: The sorting works, but while sorting another clone has been made...

Comment: Creating a [Stack Snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) may be of great benefit here, so it's easy for others to see what's going on.

Comment: Holy, huge post now, sorry for that... But I've created a snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, I think, was that you were appending items, just continually adding them on top of each other.
Calling `.empty()` first will clear out the previous item.

The line in question:

```
$(this).empty().append(dragging);
```

The above combined with Jeroen's `accept` line fixes the issue:

```
$("li.placeholder").droppable({
        revert: false,
        accept: "#draggable li",
        drop: function (event, ui) {

            var dragging = ui.draggable.clone();

            $(this).empty().append(dragging);

        }

    });
```

Working JS fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/csqch2g3/1/

Comment: Can you please correct my name? haha jereon -> jeroen :D

Comment: @JeroenBellemans eessh how did I spell that wrong? My bad. :O

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution, I've added this to the droppable function:

`accept: "#draggable li"`

Yup, that was the solution..